# A thread is blocked at java.io.PrintStream.println

Tags: multithreading, block

I met a problem that the thread is blocked at java.io.PrintStream.println.
Is there any body know what may cause that?
The thread is doing System.out.println but blocked.

```
Below is the trace of the blocked thread:
    "Binder_1" prio=5 tid=9 MONITOR
    | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4197e810 self=0x71c16fe8
    | sysTid=2872 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1879251944
    | state=S schedstat=( 28753697 30516930 198 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=3
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:~525)
    - waiting to lock <0x418e8458> (a java.io.PrintStream) held by            tid=1         
(main)
   at                                                                             com.android.commands.monkey.Monkey$ActivityController.activityStarting(Monkey.java:292)
  at android.app.IActivityController$Stub.onTransact(IActivityController.java:62)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Regarding the thread of tid=1 (main), below is the trace:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 MONITOR
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4163ae58 self=0x4155a820
  | sysTid=957 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074270548
  | state=S schedstat=( 152811485739 161565519532 434804 ) utm=10108 stm=5173 core=3
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:~14181)
  - waiting to lock <0x41f6a218> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService) held by tid=48 (Binder_5)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.broadcastStickyIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:97)
  at com.android.server.BatteryService$10.run(BatteryService.java:786)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:1168)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1265)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't think the main thread is occupying the
    System.out.println
because it is also blocked for something but not doing
    System.out.println

---

```
"Binder_5" prio=5 tid=48 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x427f6f00 self=0x76ddbc60
  | sysTid=1552 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1994241064
  | state=S schedstat=( 221394418709 101632316635 622311 ) utm=17405 stm=4734 core=3
  #00  pc 000206e4  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002cf4b  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d3e9  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001d8d3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+42)
  #04  pc 0001dadb  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+118)
  #05  pc 0001978d  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+30)
  #06  pc 000736c5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #07  pc 000203cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #08  pc 00051097  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
  #09  pc 00029860  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #10  pc 00030d34  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #11  pc 0002e3cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #12  pc 000634fd  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  #13  pc 0004fdfd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #14  pc 0006dea3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #15  pc 00073413  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #16  pc 00019221  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+60)
  #17  pc 0001d795  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+508)
  #18  pc 0001db13  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+38)
  #19  pc 0001db89  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
  #20  pc 00021995  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #21  pc 0000ea5d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #22  pc 0004e131  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #23  pc 0000e58f  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #24  pc 0000d230  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #25  pc 0000d3c8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
  at android.app.IActivityController$Stub$Proxy.activityStarting(IActivityController.java:172)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1223)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:764)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3226)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3204)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:136)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2160)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: I think you should look why the main thread is blocked. Can you post what is happening in thread  held by tid=48 (Binder_5)?

Comment: HI, below is binder_5:

Comment: Hello, I posted the trace of binder_5. I think it is doing a binder request but not get reply. And the server side of the binder is just the thread which is blocked by io.